# ArrayField not recognized in Django 3.1.4 for MongoDB database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-models

I am trying to use [the `ArrayField` in Django ORM](https://www.djongomapper.com/using-django-with-mongodb-array-field/), but it is not recognized.

This is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import forms

# Create your models here.

class Produtos(models.Model):
    authors : models.ArrayField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't have an `ArrayField`; that is something that Djongo adds.

Instead of using `django.db.models`, use `djongo.models`:

```py
from djongo import models  # <-- here
from django.forms import forms

class Produtos(models.Model):
    authors = models.ArrayField()
```

Also, make sure to use `=` instead of `:` when creating your model's attributes as I have done above.